# Appcelerator Studio - not loading after upgrade

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-studio

I've just upgraded to the new version of Appcelerator Studio and now when I try to start it I get an error.

When I start the app I'm asked for my email and password and after entering credentials I get the following error message:

```
Login Error

module.js:327
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'fstream'
     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:325:15)
     at Function.Module._load (module.js:276:25)
     at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
     at require (internal/module.js:12:17)
     at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/node_modules/appcelerator/node_modules/tar/lib/entry.js:14:15)
     at Module._compile (module.js:387:26)
     at Object.Module._extensions.js (module.js:404:10)
     at Module.load (module.js:343:32)
     at Function.Module._load (module.js:300:12)
     at Module.require (module.js:353:17)
```

I've also tried downloading setup from the site and reinstalling - didn't help.

I'm running on MAC OS X.

Comment: Stack Overflow is [not the right place](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255745/why-were-not-customer-support-for-your-favorite-company) to report bugs. Please check if this is a known issue at the [Appcelerator JIRA](https://jira.appcelerator.org/). If it's not, create a ticket, link to this question but also provide reproducible code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've had this as well, thought it was some kind of an issue at my system, but I'll report it.

You can resolve this by reinstalling the Appcelerator CLI:

```
sudo npm i -g appcelerator
appc use 5.2.0 --force
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reinstall cli and got this:

```
Annas-iMac:bin annakozy$ sudo npm i -g appcelerator
Password:
npm WARN install:object-assign ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/usr/local/etc/lib/node_modules/appcelerator/node_modules/got/node_modules/object-assign' -> '/usr/local/etc/lib/node_modules/appcelerator/node_modules/got/node_modules/object-assign'
npm WARN install:ansi-regex ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/usr/local/etc/lib/node_modules/appcelerator/node_modules/update-notifier/node_modules/ansi-regex' -> '/usr/local/etc/lib/node_modules/appcelerator/node_modules/update-notifier/node_modules/ansi-regex'
npm WARN install:ansi-styles ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/usr/local/etc/lib/node_modules/appcelerator/node_modules/update-notifier/node_modules/ansi-styles' -> '/usr/local/etc/lib/node_modules/appcelerator/node_modules/update-notifier/node_modules/ansi-styles'
npm WARN install:supports-color ENOENT: no such file or directory, rename '/usr/local/etc/lib/node_modules/appcelerator/node_modules/update-notifier/node_modules/supports-color' -> '/usr/local/etc/lib/node_modules/appcelerator/node_modules/update-notifier/node_modules/supports-color' object-assign@3.0.0 node_modules/appcelerator/node_modules/got/node_modules/object-assign -> node_modules/appcelerator/node_modules/got/node_modules/object-assign ansi-regex@2.0.0 node_modules/appcelerator/node_modules/update-notifier/node_modules/ansi-regex -> node_modules/appcelerator/node_modules/update-notifier/node_modules/ansi-regex ansi-styles@2.2.0 node_modules/appcelerator/node_modules/update-notifier/node_modules/ansi-styles -> node_modules/appcelerator/node_modules/update-notifier/node_modules/ansi-styles has-ansi@2.0.0 node_modules/appcelerator/node_modules/update-notifier/node_modules/has-ansi -> node_modules/appcelerator/node_modules/update-notifier/node_modules/has-ansi strip-ansi@3.0.1 node_modules/appcelerator/node_modules/update-notifier/node_modules/strip-ansi -> node_modules/appcelerator/node_modules/update-notifier/node_modules/strip-ansi supports-color@2.0.0 node_modules/appcelerator/node_modules/update-notifier/node_modules/supports-color -> node_modules/appcelerator/node_modules/update-notifier/node_modules/supports-color chalk@1.1.1 node_modules/appcelerator/node_modules/update-notifier/node_modules/chalk -> node_modules/appcelerator/node_modules/update-notifier/node_modules/chalk - /usr/local/etc/lib/node_modules/appcelerator/node_modules/update-notifier node_modules/appcelerator/node_modules/update-notifier /usr/local/etc/lib └── (empty)

npm ERR! code 1
```